# Jmeter beanshell postProcessor parse json from previous api error

Tags: jmeter-plugins

my Json response looks like (get from previous api get list):

```
{
"response": {
    "status": 0,
    "startRow": 0,
    "endRow": 17,
    "totalRows": 18,
    "data": [ {
        "id": "5703962be4b05600341bcbef",
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdDate": 1459852843761,
        "lastModifiedBy": null,
        "lastModifiedDate": 1459908526375,
        "version": 4,
        "country": "SG",
        "name": "Singapore",
        "slug": "test"
    }, {
        "id": "5703999be4b0d1b6145cf5b6",
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdDate": 1459853723503,
        "lastModifiedBy": null,
        "lastModifiedDate": 1460532423470,
        "version": 1,
        "country": "MY",
        "name": "Putrajaya",
        "slug": "putrajaya"
    }],
    "totalPages": null,
    "exception": null
}
```

}

my jmeter and it's error on pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4y2j.jpg

json-simple, json minimal ... are added on lib

but i got an error on picture.
could anyone know about that issue or i miss something else ...

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double check your response data, it looks empty to me:

[image: Empty json response]

Also be aware of alternative options:

1. JMeter 3.2 comes with [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which can be used for extracting "interesting" response fields. Also there is [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) just in case if JSON Extractor is not enough
2. JMeter 3.2 comes with [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language support and Groovy in its turn has built-in [JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so you can switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and parse your JSON using Groovy. See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for details.

Comment: Hello Dmitri,

If i want to edit value of "country" & "name" (then send body to api edit), how can I do (continue use beanshell). 

thank you so much!